# Should we store App Engine Context in a global var versus creating it for every request?

Tags: google-app-engine, go

We currently generate the App Engine context on every single request. We've read elsewhere, that this doesn't matter as App Engine essentially caches the context anyway.

```
func addHandler(res http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    c := appengine.NewContext(req)
```

Our question: Would it make any sense to store the App Engine context in a global variable?

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest against it for the following reasons:

1. Keeping global state is always a hazard: it could go stale, corrupted and generally speaking it breaks isolation and encapsulation.
2. Due to the way AppEngine works as you scale up or out, you don't how truly global that global really is and what other requests might be reading/writing to it.
3. Concurrency. Global variables are the bane of concurrency. Save yourselves your sanity and don't use global variables for a web app.

Comment: How can I keep my functions decoupled? Needing the Context everywhere, even for logging, requires that business logic functions that shouldn't even need to know that there is a request, have to have the Context passed in. That makes unit testing significantly more difficult.

Comment: Without knowing the specifics of the architecture, I'd say look into having sort sort of MVC-style pattern. Let the controller deal with requests and pass whatever data is necessary to a model with business logic and the return whatever needs to be returned to the controller and it to the view (whether it's an actual view or just a json response).

Comment: Sure, that's what we're trying to accomplish. Logging to syslog inside of a model or having the model make an external http request (my current use case) or writing to the datastore don't seem like they should require access to the initial request. It's the blurring of model and controller that is causing me grief.

Comment: Yes, I've encountered use cases where you definitely need to blend/blur the lines between models/controllers and utilities. It's the "price to pay" given then constraints of the platform.